# Can I terminate all sessions of Outlook web?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have an issue with my former employer. I left the company on a bad note and he has access to my personal outlook account since it was saved in the browser on a computer in the office.

He is changing passwords of various websites and changing my outlook password does not seem to help. What can I do? Is there a way to terminate all outlook sessions?

Really annoying that after changing the password he still is able to do this.

I am talking about outlook web, not the client.

Comment: Try https://login.microsoftonline.com/logout.srf and https://login.live.com/logout.srf . After changing your password, setup 2FA if it isn't already.

Comment: This is illegal. Report it to the police.